# Using boost::interprocess condition variable on an already locked mutex

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, interprocess

I want to use boost::interprocess condition variable on an already locked mutex. I have locked the mutex already using `mutex->lock();` function and because of this [scoped_lock](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/scoped_lock.html) is not really appropriate for me. Is there any API available in boost::interprocess to wait on a condition variable without using `scoped_lock`? I am looking for an API that looks similar to below:

```cpp
condition_variable.wait(mutex)
```

In the above code block, the mutex is already locked so there is no need for the `scoped_lock`. However, the above code block doesn't work because boost expects a `lock` instead of `mutex` as the first argument to `wait. I could do the same in the pthread using the function call below:

```cpp
pthread_cond_wait(condition_variable, mutex)
```

Comment: What are the [types of the condition variable and mutex}(https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-synchronization#:~:text=a%20different%20process.-,Boost.,referenced%20from%20programs%20by%20name.)?

Comment: The condition variable is a `interprocess_condition` and the mutex is a `interprocess_mutex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a BasicLockable. Indeed scoped_lock (or lock_guard) are not that. `unique_lock` and similar are:

> The class `unique_lock` meets the `BasicLockable` requirements. If `Mutex`
> meets the Lockable requirements, `unique_lock` also meets the `Lockable`
> requirements (ex.: can be used in `std::lock`); if `Mutex` meets the
> `TimedLockable` requirements, `unique_lock` also meets the `TimedLockable`
> requirements.

Here's a small demo assuming some types for your interprocess mutex and condition:

**[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed7d439ffdb3b22e)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using namespace std::literals;

using boost::posix_time::milliseconds;
auto now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time;

int main() {
    bip::managed_mapped_file mmf(bip::open_or_create, "mapped.dat", 32<<10);

    auto& mutex = *mmf.find_or_construct<bip::interprocess_mutex>("mutex")();
    auto& cond  = *mmf.find_or_construct<bip::interprocess_condition>("cond")();
    auto& data  = *mmf.find_or_construct<int>("data")(0);

    auto is_ready = [&data] { return data != 42; };

    std::unique_lock lk(mutex);

    /*void*/ cond.wait(lk);

    /*void*/ cond.wait(lk, is_ready);

    // check return values for these:
    cond.timed_wait(lk, now() + milliseconds(120));
    cond.timed_wait(lk, now() + milliseconds(120), is_ready);
}
```

(Of course that would just block forever because nothing ever notifies the condition).

> Added a *running* demo with a very quick-and-dirty signaller thread: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1eb29653f1bbcee

### Without Standard Library

You can use the equivalent Boost types: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks

Comment: Added a _running_ demo with a very quick-and-dirty signaller thread: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1eb29653f1bbcee

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I didn't know that standard library locks can be used with boost interprocess locks.